# Perimeter problem involving different sized sticks?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving

Could you please help me find the answer to this question. I think it has something to do with grouping or pairing some numbers.I would appreciate easy-to-understand solutions. Thank you.

There are 99 sticks of lengths 1,2,3...,99 respectively, the width of the sticks can be ignored. Is it possible to form the perimeter of a rectangle using all the sticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $1,2,$ and $3$ for the short ends of the rectangle. That leaves $4,5,\ldots,99$ to divide into two equal sets. Note that $4+99=5+98=\cdots=51+52$. How many such pairs are there?

Comment: Are their 43 pairs? Once I find the number of pairs, what do I do? I am confused.

Comment: No, there are not 43 pairs.

Comment: Are there 48 pairs of 103 then?

Comment: Yes. Now what can you do with these pairs?

Comment: I can divide it by 2 so that there are 24 pairs of 103 on either long side of the rectangle.

Comment: Well done! Now, as a bonus, which numbers apart from $99$ does this construction work for?